# mongoimport json with backslash - mongoimport tool how to escape

Tags: mongodb

I am using the mongoimport and it fails on my json for this line:

```
{ "username": "user@example.com", "password": "abscdexample\"},
```

any idea how to escape this \ backslash which I believe is the problem? I dont want to hash/salt or manipulate the password stored in the database. This is for research purposes and not used for securing any system.

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
{ "username": "user@example.com", "password": "abscdexample\/"}
```

This would escape character